# Why do I only print the first letters of each item in the list?

Tags: python

I was wondering why I only print the first letter of each item I input. I would like for it to loop through the list and print each item that starts with one of the letters in the first_letters variable.

```
phrase = input('Enter a list: ')
first_letters = ['A','B','C','D']
for name in phrase:
    if name[0] in first_letters: 
        print(name)

#['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot']
```

Comment: How are you entering the data? Can you give an exact sample of your input?

Comment: Also, is this Python 2 or 3? `input` behaves very differently for each.

Comment: This is P3, i enter the input as 'Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot'

Answer (score 0):

If this is Python3, then the list you are entering is not actually a list but a string. So when you call,

```
for name in phrase:
```

you are calling each letter in that string. So the variable `name` is actually one letter so `name[0]` is equal to `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input as:

```
Alpha, Bravo, Charlie, Delta, Echo, Foxtrot
```

This complicates handling your input a bit. Because you are now going to have to deal with a space and a comma between each word.

Upon entering your user input, handle all spaces, and then use `split` to actually obtain a list of your entries. So:

```
phrase = input('Enter a list: ').replace(' ', '').split(',')
```

phrase will now be a list that looks like:

```
['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot']
```

It would probably easier to just handle a space separated list like:

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo Foxtrot
```

Then, you can just call `split()` without that `replace` method, and utilize its default split-on-space:

```
phrase = input('Enter a list: ').split()
```

Now you are iterating over your list and you can now check the first letter of each word with your `first_letters` list.

To ensure you always compare to the exact same casing, make sure you call `upper()` for each iteration in your list, to compare to the same case in your list:

```
phrase = input('Enter a list: ').replace(' ', '').split(',')
first_letters = ['A','B','C','D']
for name in phrase:
    if name[0].upper() in first_letters:
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
```

Answer (score 0):

For input Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot

If you are entering comma after each name you enter use .split(',') if you are just using space between names use .split()

.split() looks for an empty space and splits the user input after space and .split(',') looks for comma and splits the user input after finding comma.

```
phrase = input('Enter a list: ').split(',')
first_letters = ['A','B','C','D']
for name in phrase:
   if name[0].upper() in first_letters:
      print(name)
```

To see the list of names

```
print(phrase)
```

it will show you the names in a list form after using .split() or .split(',')

['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot']

**Output:**

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
```

If you want the correct names even when you use lowercase letters use this code

```
phrase = input('Enter a list: ').split(',')
first_letters = ['A','B','C','D','a','b','c','d']
for name in phrase:
   if name[0] in first_letters:
      print(name)
```

For input Alpha,Bravo,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot

**Output:**

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
alpha
bravo
charlie
delta
```